# IndexOutOfBoundsException in LinkedList

Tags: java

I'm getting IndexOutOfBoundsException, which looks like kind of impossible to me.

Code:

```
public class SomethingCalculator {

    @Nullable
    private Config mConfig;
    @Nullable
    private Long mTime;
    final private List<Long> mLinkedList = new LinkedList<>();


    public synchronized void setupWithConfiguration(Config config, Long time) {
        //config and time are non null always
        mTime = time;
        mConfig = config;
        generatLookUp();
    }


    public synchronized void reset() {
        mConfig = null;
        mTime = null;
        mLinkedList.clear();
    }


    @Nullable
    public synchronized Long getTheValue(long ms) {
        if (mConfig == null)
            return null;

        // getting exception here
        if (ms > mLinkedList.get(mLinkedList.size() - 1)) {
            return 0l; // something
        }
        return 0l; // something
    }


    private synchronized void generatLookUp() {
        mLinkedList.clear();
        if (mConfig == null || mTime==null)
            return;
        // mLinkedList will always have size > 0 after executing this
        // based upon config this method add elements to mLinkedList

        // adding dummy values
        mLinkedList.add(1L);
        mLinkedList.add(2L);
    }
}
```

getting an exception while calling `SomethingCalculator.getTheValue()`

**Exception:**

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 0
 at java.util.LinkedList.checkElementIndex(LinkedList.java:565)
```

Not sure if mMylinkedList.size() returns 4 then how mMylinkedList.get(4) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?  When you debug what is the state?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? It's hard to tell what's going on just from this piece of code. Are there multiple threads involved? (I know this is synchronized, but I suspect it may still be relevant.)

Comment: @Tayler , OP has mentioned which line..

Comment: yes multiple threads can invoke these methods but as they are synchronized this should not be an issue.

Comment: You should check the index boundaries before accessing index. even java implementation does it

Comment: Not sure why its down voted, please leave a comment before down voting, this will help to improve question.

Comment: Actual code already took care of index boundaries, The example i shared already shows size of list is 4, there should not be an issue to get element at index 3.

Comment: The code you posted can't throw that exception. Post actual code. At the current state this question is useless hence the down and close votes.

Comment: @H4SN no, size is 0 and one thread is trying to access index 4, hence the error

Comment: @lainatnavi method is synchronized so only one thread can access at a time.

Comment: @JonSkeet updated my question with actual code, just removed some actual calculation.

Comment: @Oleg updated the question.

Comment: While this may well be actual code, it's not a complete example - it refers to code we don't know about (`Config`) and doesn't have anything we can actually *run*. We're looking for an example we can copy, paste, compile and run, so that we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Updated question with dummy values, for any non null config mLinked will always be non empty after executing `generatLookUp`

Comment: yes other threads can call reset but they have to wait, until `getTheValue` returns.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is still not helpful. Post complete reproducible example that includes usage of your class. If access to the list is synchronized the size of `mLinkedList` can't be 0 after `mLinkedList.size()` returned `5`. In the code you posted the access is synchronized which means something else is going on in the code you haven't posted. As long as you will continue to post demo code that shows synchronized access to the list nothing fruitful will happen.

Comment: well access to list is synchronized, all methods in class are synchronized and no other class reference to `mLinkedList` Already debugged it to me it seems impossible that's why posted question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into generated AAR it was found that the `synchronized` keyword was stripped thus this exception can occur. The `synchronized` keyword was stripped due to a proguard optimization.

Removed this:

```
-optimizations !method/marking/synchronized
```

Now i can see `synchronized` keyword in the generated AAR.